# how can I integrate the Apport tool with Zammad Api?

Tags: bug-reporting, apport

i want to resolve an integration between Zammad Api and Apport, what can i do for it?? i tried installing zammad.py and zammad api, and Zammad platform,

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].